# MoveWindow API doesn't work well on Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista

I have an application on Vista which loops through all processes and finds associated main windows in order to move and resize them.

The problem is that some windows get moved and resized and some don't. Also it even seems that moved and resized windows aren't moved and resized according to the MoveWindow function call because they are resized to title bar and all of them are on the same line (same y coordinate).

Here's the sample code:

```
IntPtr handle;
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

int i = 0;
foreach (Process process in processList)
{
     handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

     if (handle != IntPtr.Zero) //If the process has window then move and resize it.
     {
          bool moveResult = MoveWindow(handle, i * 50, i * 50, 500, 500, true);
          i++;
     }
}
```

Is this because of Vista? What alternative should I use?

Comment: What's up with processes with multiple windows? And wouldn't it make sense to check if the window is visible, first?

Comment: Let's keep it simple: processes have only one window and all windows are visible, but even then some windows don't get moved at all and others are minimized to title bar and not 500x500 pixels.

Comment: So you're not running it on a real windows system then? Just a hypothetical one where all of the processes have only one window (this never happens)

Comment: I am running it on a real windows system but I am only interested in main windows for the processes. For example, I have WINWORD process with one active window but MoveWindow doesn't have any effect on it. On the other hand MoveWindow resizes Visual Studio window but not with 500x500 size and not on the correct position. I cannot understand why.

Comment: I have added this line of code instead of MoveWindow:

    SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 400, 400, 800, 800, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

This command made my application top most but did not resize it to 800x800pixels, nor did put it on x=400, y=400 location, but x=400, y=0 (no matter what I put, y is always zero). Needless to say that this line of code didn't work for other applications but only for the process owner. Is there any expert to help! I am running this code on Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MoveWindow function doesn't have any effect on the minimized windows. So, before MoveWindow I used ShowWindow:

ShowWindow(handle, 3); //ShowMaximized = 3

This helped!

I used SetWindowPos function but MSDN documentation about this function says that in Vista "hwnd and window manager operations are only effective inside a session and cross-session attempts to manipulate the hwnd will fail" and that statement indicated that problem is because of Vista.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=VS.85%29.aspx